# three way lookups to add values to a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to fill out the table 1 with the sales values in table 2. But I keep getting `#N/A`.

Below is one of my attempts.

`=INDEX(Table2[#All],MATCH([@ACODE],Table2[[#All],[ACODE]],0),MATCH([@CITY],Table2[[#All],[CITY]],0), MATCH(Table1[[#Headers],[2/1/2019]],Table2[[#All],[DATES]],0))`

How could I achieve my expected result?

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to just use a PivotTable with "ACODE" and "CITY" in the Rows, "Dates" in the Columns, and "Sales" in the Values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SUMIFS formula is probably the easiest way, it would look like this:

```
=SUMIFS(Table2[SALES],Table2[ACODE],[@ACODE],Table2[CITY],[@CITY],Table2[DATES],Table1[#Headers])
```